# Display referencing entity in panels

Tags: panels, entities

I have two content types.
1. Lecture
2. Notes

Notes have an entity reference field which references lecture.
Different users create different notes each referencing to a lecture.

Now,
How do I display note created by user on lectures page.

Answer (score 1):

I know how to do it with Views and Panels modules.
First you need to create two Views:

1. First one is **Lecture_view** create a block and add fields you want to display(Title, body, most important - **Content: Nid**  and any other fields your Content type has).
2. Second one is **Notes** view, create same block but fields for notes to display, and also in a
   **Contextual filters** menu add  new filter `(Content) Content: Nid`

Now you should go to *Lecture view* and in **Advanced** menu, click on **theme** *information* link, and you need to create template file, find row with `Field Content: Nid` and create one of suggested fields, something like `(views-view-field--conversations--page--nid-1.tpl.php) in /sites/all/themes/YOURTHEMENAME/views/YOURVIEWNAME(lecture_view--block)/YOURTEMPLATEFILE(views-view-field--conversations--page--nid-1.tpl.php)` in this file you will past code from theme view, its something similar to

```
<?php print render($output); ?>
```

you need to add one more thing embed that views:

```
<?php print views_embed_view('notes', $display_id='default', $row->nid); ?>
```

your contextual filter should work, and now you can add this view to your Panel to display, in Panel menu.

***Maybe this is not the best way to do this***